# How to deploy objects with different schema using DACPAC from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

.NET database deployment solution where we are creating and upgrading our databases using DACPACS (using `DacPackage`, `DacDeployOptions`, `DacServices` classes).

The default schema is set as `dbo` in the SQL project properties, so all the database objects are now created in the `dbo` schema.

Requirement: I need an implementation to create/upgrade stored procedures and functions with different schema only. Ignore rest of the objects (tables, views, triggers etc) in the database.

Please suggest: how can I create/upgrade objects with different schema other than `dbo` in this case?

Comment: I found this link helpful to modify and update the DACPAC file. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1080452/Parameterize-Schema-Name-in-SSDT-Database-Project

Answer (score 0):

In your sqlproj create the schema, do this my adding your new schema to the project create file SchemaB.sql with

```
CREATE SCHEMA [SchemaB]
```

Then prefix the object names, with the schema

```
CREATE TABLE [SchemaB].[Address]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Street] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

In the deployment option you can set that you only want to deploy specific types of objects, these options are stored in the publish file with your project, use this as input to the SqlPackage.exe command when deploying.

Comment: what is the option name under publish file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio (using VS 2022):

- Right click on your Db Project
- Choose Add/New Item
- Choose Security
- Choose Schema
- Name your [yourSchemaName]

It should create a file named "[yourSchemaName].sql", containing:

CREATE SCHEMA [yourSchemaName]